Angular velocity vs Angular frequency
Are these two omega same? (angular frequency of a current oscillating loop and angular velocity of a rotating body)

Yes, these are the same. Angular velocity and angular frequency both have the units rads * s^-1. rads is a unitless scalar, while s^-1 is usually in hz.

They are synonyms. Frequency is number of turns per second. Since we know that one turn is $2\pi$ radians, we can extrapolate angular frequency $\omega = 2\pi \nu$. Which then will be measured by $rad/s$ or in other words how big rotation angle is accumulated in system after 1 second of continuous rotation.
